# c# syntax checking

Tags: c#, syntax

I create a project, and add a file. I can build an exe and so on, works fine.

Question is: what if I have multiple files in my project and I want to check the syntax of my code in one single file, and don't want to build an exe or dll?

When programming c, I press ctrl+F7 in the Visual Studio IDE and that compiles my code. I understand that there are no object files in c#. Microsoft c# reference states: "There are no object (.obj) files created as a result of invoking the C# compiler; output files are created directly.".

Is there a csc.exe switch to tell me 'ok your code looks fine', or 'the expression at line xx doesn't make sense'?

Note: please do not give the link to Command-line Building With csc.exe. All the sample command lines are for creating an exe or dll, from one or multiple files. Or on how to exclude a file from building. I don't want that.

Comment: When you compile your code, the compiler will tell you of any syntax errors or warnings.

Comment: The background compiler in VS does a pretty good job of telling you if there are syntax errors.

Comment: I assume you are new to C# IDE / Programming / etc.. here is a [MSDN Getting started with Visual Studio](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a72418yk(v=vs.110).aspx) Link that you should read

Comment: why not creating a one file project: would that work? Say, if I have a partial class, and the other part is in another file that I don't want to add to this project? Or if the objects of classes I use are in other files? No need to tell me how, a simple yes/no would be enough.dbugger seems to have edited my post to remove the part I said I'm completely new to c#. Things trivial to you may not be as simple to me.

Comment: @Junipella: What are you actually trying to do?  If you want to know if your code has compile-time errors, compile it.  The compiler will tell you about any errors.  It's really not clear what you're asking or why.

Comment: @dbugger background compiler in VS: what if I don't use the Visual Studio IDE? If Microsoft has decided not to give me this feature, that's fine. I couldn't find the compiler switch to give me what I find, that's why I'm asking here.

Comment: @David I'm asking wether the c# compiler can perform this task: parse a file, tell me if the contents of the file are a legit c# code.

Comment: Then you are at the mercy of whatever IDE you are using.

Comment: @Junipella: Yes, the C# compiler is capable of determining whether or not C# code is valid.  That's... a pretty significant part of what a compiler does.  It wouldn't be a very effective compiler if it couldn't.

Comment: @David: Of course it is. I restate the question: In a multiple file project, can I take one file and ask the compiler if it contains legit c# code? If I have, say, a 200 file project and the compile time is, say, 20 minutes, do I have to wait some minutes to find out if I did something wrong in one file?

Comment: @Junipella: 20 minutes is a pretty significant compile time.  200 files really isn't a lot.  I've *never* seen a C# project with *that* long of a compile time.  To more specifically address your question though, if that one file has dependencies on other files (such as referencing classes defined in the other files) then it won't be able to compile without them.  It won't be valid C# code if it contains undefined identifiers.  Organizing your code into smaller components would go a long way to addressing this problem.  (Because 20 minutes is ridiculous for one project.)

Comment: @David: 20 minutes was an arbitrary time. Might have written 3 minutes as well, wouldn't have made any difference. The question still stands: if I change one thing in one file, do I have to wait the build time of the whole project?

Answer (score 2):

The compiler is the syntax checker.  It will tell you if your C# code is valid or not when it compiles it.  Any errors or warnings will be available at the end of the attempted compilation.  If there are none, then it's valid code.

You can individually compile any arbitrary piece of C# code any time you like.  *However*, if that code depends on *other code* then in order for it to be valid that other code will need to be included in the compilation as well.  Code which uses otherwise undefined symbols (such as classes defined in other code files) isn't valid.  Those symbols need to be defined.

In the comments above you indicate a concern that such compilation of an entire project might take a long time.  This would be addressed by organizing your code into smaller components.  If you have one enormous C# project that takes a long time to compile, then what you have is a mess.  Break it apart into smaller components.  Each of those components can be in their own projects which can be compiled separately.  Different projects will depend on each other, and dependent projects will be included in that compilation.  But *that* dependency graph *also* shouldn't be too large and unwieldy.  If it is, you still have a mess but just on a different scale.  Keep the dependency graph shallow and maintainable between your projects.

Answer (score 0):

Sort of answering my own question. When I posted this I wasn't aware that splitting definition and implementation in c#, as you did in c or c++, was not possible. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/64800602-4ff2-4747-8c42-a4e1980d4124/c-no-header-files-all-code-is-written-inline-why?forum=csharplanguage states that Interfaces do this, but not in a way I asked in the original post. Looks like in a multi file project, only the IDE gives me this piece of information (syntax checking), other than building the whole project.

It appears that ctrl+F7 on a single file (Visual Studio), or -c or -fsyntax-only switches (on gcc) are not possible with c#.